# For loop runs forever

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm watching a Udemy course about Swift (called "the Complete iOS 8 and Swift course") and a piece of code that the instructor is using as an example isn't working as shown for me.

Not getting an actual *error* in my code. The for loop doesn't stop and I'm stumped as to why.

```
for var i = 1; i < 10; i + 1 {

println(i)

}
```

(Xcode version 6.1.1)

Comment: You probably need `i = i + 1 `  as the last expression.

Comment: Ah, that worked. Thanks. Do you know why this got voted down so much? Did I do something wrong? @HoboSapiens

Comment: You can get downvotes for many reasons. In this case I'd guess people thought this was a trivial error that you should have picked up from the course material yourself.

Comment: @HoboSapiens Good point. Yet from my understanding this is a website to _ask_ questions.

Comment: @RyanKaldi: correct. Also, people are free to vote on the general usefulness of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop `i` will always be 1. You are using i + 1 for incrementing the counter variable but you are not assigning the value back.

So either you use:

```
for var i = 1; i < 10; i = i + 1
{
    println(i)
}
```

**or**

```
for var i = 1; i < 10; i++
{
    println(i)
}
```

Comment: Oh. Makes sense. Im still a beginner at coding so I'm still learning these little things. Thank you for your help. Any idea why I got voted down so much? Did I do something wrong? @MidhunMP

Comment: @RyanKaldi: The downvoter have their own opinion about the downvote. So I can't say why they did it. But in my opinion, your question is under a typographical error and you are not showing any research effort. Also something like "Why isn't the code working". That's why you got these many downvotes.

Comment: @RyanKaldi: Don't worry, all starts like this. In future before asking a question please check http://stackoverflow.com/help